# How to show a hidden data inside dataTables using status in jQuery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax

My problem is I can't separate a data and inside data's value and put it in its corresponding status. What I did is there are three  status named`:` `approved`, `pending`, `cancelled`. These 3 status are updated in my database. Their values are `0`, `1`, `2`. What I did is inside my ajax PHP file I called a whole table and then provide a stored procedure in it, and inside my database for updating the status, I created two tables inside `MySQL`, so `1st table` is for the data that are registered because what I did is by group or by batch since I used a dataTables too upon registration of data, `2nd table` I created is for the purpose of acting like a mother table because I want to group the grouped registered data inside my `1st table`, now this is why I am confused because I use both `PHP` and `jQuery/Ajax` so please bear with me for it is complicated for me on how will I explain this in a simple and short. The question is how will I separate them according to its status? is it possible using only manipulation of HTML DOM Elements? . Sorry for the long code but it's the only way I can explain further my problem. I am stuck for a week I hope someone can help me. I will elaborate more if something is kind of hard to comprehend

Here is the image when registering the data

[image]

Image when registered it will automatically set it into pending status. (The CONTROL-1381 is the example of unique ID that I created to make the data from my 1st table be grouped as one in my 2nd table, so this is the result of my 2nd table).

[image]

Inside this mother value which is from 2nd table in SQL

[image]

Once I select optional data that I want to cancel

[image]

Once updated it will proceed to my status cancelled but the remaining pending status is gone

[image]

Inside of the cancelled data is the data that I picked but the rest is gone

[image]

Here is my snippet code in my dataTable

```js
function RequestChange() {

  $("#dataTables").DataTable().destroy();
  $("#tb_body").empty();

  var changeValue = $('#stats').val();
  // alert(changeValue);

  if (changeValue == '1') {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax_tools_approval.php",
      data: {
        status: changeValue
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // alert(response);
        $("#dataTables").append(response);
        $("#dataTables").DataTable();
      }
    });
  } else if (changeValue == "2") {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax_tools_approval.php",
      data: {
        status: changeValue
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // alert(response);

        $("#dataTables").append(response);
        $("#dataTables").DataTable();
      }
    });
  } else {
    $.ajax({
      type: "POST",
      url: "ajax_tools_approval.php",
      data: {
        status: changeValue
      },
      success: function(response) {
        // alert(response);
        $("#dataTables").append(response);
        $("#dataTables").DataTable();
      }
    });
  }
}

// Startup
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#stats').change(function() {
    $(this).val();
  });

  $("#stats").trigger('change');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="wrapper">
  <div id="page-wrapper">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

      </div>
    </div>
    <br>
    <br>
    <div>
      <form action="GET">
        <div class="form-group">
          <label> Table group by Status </label>
          <select name="selector_id" onchange="RequestChange()" style="width:200px;" class="show-menu-arrow form-control" id="stats">
            <option value="" disabled selected> Select Status </option>
            <option value="1"> APPROVED </option>
            <option value="0"> PENDING </option>
            <option value="2"> CANCELLED </option>
          </select>
        </div>
      </form>
    </div>
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
        <div class="panel panel-primary">
          <div class="panel-heading">
            Tools Approval
          </div>
          <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="row">
              <div class="col-lg-12">
                <div class="row">
                  <div class="col-lg-12">
                    <div class="panel panel-default">
                      <div class="panel-heading">
                        Request Control
                      </div>
                      <div class="panel-body">
                        <div class="table-responsive">
                          <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables">
                            <thead>
                              <tr>
                                <th> Request Number </th>
                                <th> Department </th>
                                <th> Section / Model </th>
                                <th> Leader </th>
                                <th> Reason </th>
                                <th>
                                  <center> Status </center>
                                </th>
                              </tr>
                            </thead>
                            <tbody id="tb_body">

                            </tbody>
                          </table>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                  </div>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Here is my code inside CONTROL-1381

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-lg-12">
    <div class="panel panel-default">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        Emailed Data for approval
      </div>
      <!-- /.panel-heading -->
      <div class="panel-body">
        <div class="table-responsive">

          <table width="100%" class="table table-striped table-bordered table-hover" id="dataTables">
            <thead>
              <tr>
                <th>
                  <center>
                    Select Data
                    <input type="checkbox" id="select_all" 
                     class="select_all">
                  </center>
                </th>
                <th> Control Number </th>
                <th> Tools Specification </th>
                <th> Supplier </th>
                <th>
                  <center> Status </center>
                </th>
                <th>
                  <center> # </center>
                </th>

              </tr>
            </thead>
            <?php                                                                  
               $con->next_result();                                               
               $result = mysqli_query($con,"CALL   
                GetAllRequestedTools('$check_stats')"); ?>
              <tbody>

                <?php 
                                                                                     
                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))                         
                { 
                                                                                     
                   $tool_stats = $row['req_stats'];
                                                                                     
                   if($row['tr_main'] == $tid)                                     
                   {                                                                                                                                    
                   if($rows['tools_stats'] == '0')                                    
                   {
                                                         
                   //IF VALUE IS 0 DISPLAY ONLY PENDING
                                                                                      
                    if($tool_stats == '0')                                            
                    { 
                    echo "<tr>";                                                    
                  ?>

                <td>
                  <center>
                    <input name="chk_status[]" class="is_checked_status" 
                     type="checkbox" value="<?php echo $row['req_stats'];?>">
                  </center>
                </td>

                <?php
                                                                                       
                  echo "<td>" . $row['reg_input'] . "</a></td>";
                                                                                       
                  echo "<td>" . $row['reg_tools_spec'] . "</td>";
                                                                                       
                  echo "<td>" . $row['reg_supplier'] . "</td>";
                                                                                   
                ?>

                  <td>
                    <center>
                    <label data-id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" 
                     class="statusButton <?php echo ($tool_stats == 1) ? 
                     'label-success' : (($tool_stats == 2)  ? 'label-danger' 
                     : 'label-warning');?>">
                                                                                
                  <?php echo ($tool_stats == 1) ? "Approved" : 
                    (($tool_stats== 0)  ? "Pending" : "Cancelled");?>                      
                    </label>
                    </center>
                  </td>

                  <td class="hide_me">
                    <center>
                      <input name="chk_id[]" type="checkbox" 
                       class="subCheckbox" value="<?php echo 
                       $row['tools_req_id'];?>">
                    </center>
                  </td>


                  <?php
                   echo "</tr>";                                                       
                     }                                                       
                   }

                                                                            
                  //IF VALUE IS 1 DISPLAY ONLY APPROVED    
                                                                            
                    elseif($rows['tools_stats'] == '1')
                    {                                                    
                    if($tool_stats == '1')
                    {                                                         
                    echo "<tr>";                                          ?>
                    <td>
                      <center>
                        <input name="chk_status[]" class="is_checked_status" 
                         type="checkbox" value="<?php echo 
                         $row['req_stats'];?>">
                      </center>
                    </td>
                    <?php
                                    
                   echo "<td>" . $row['reg_input'] . "</a></td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['reg_tools_spec'] . "</td>";
                   echo "<td>" . $row['reg_supplier'] . "</td>";
                                                                        
                    ?>
                    <td>
                    <center>
                    <label data-id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" 
                    class="statusButton <?php echo ($tool_stats == 1) ? 
                    'label-success' : (($tool_stats == 2)  ? 'label-danger' : 
                    'label-warning');?>">
                                                                                
                    <?php echo ($tool_stats == 1) ? "Approved" : 
                      (($tool_stats == 0)  ? "Pending" : "Cancelled");?>
                                                                            
                    </label>
                    </center>
                    </td>

                      <td class="hide_me">
                        <center>
                          <input name="chk_id[]" type="checkbox" 
                           class="subCheckbox" value="<?php echo 
                           $row['tools_req_id'];?>">
                        </center>
                      </td>

                      <?php 
                                                                            
                       echo "</tr>";
                              }
                           }
                                                                            
                         //IF VALUE IS 2 DISPLAY ONLY 
                                                                            
                          elseif($rows['tools_stats'] == '2')
                          {                                                   
                          if($tool_stats == '2')
                          {
                                              
                          echo "<tr>";
                      ?>

                      <td>
                        <center>
                          <input name="chk_status[]" 
                           class="is_checked_status" type="checkbox" value=" 
                           <?php echo $row['req_stats'];?>">
                        </center>
                      </td>

                      <?php
                                                                            
                        echo "<td>" . $row['reg_input'] . "</a></td>";
                                                                            
                        echo "<td>" . $row['reg_tools_spec'] . "</td>";
                                                                            
                        echo "<td>" . $row['reg_supplier'] . "</td>";
                                                                    
                      ?>

                        <td>
                          <center>
                        <label data-id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>" 
                           class="statusButton <?php echo ($tool_stats == 1) 
                           ? 'label-success' : (($tool_stats == 2)  ? 'label- 
                           danger' : 'label-warning');?>">
                                                                                
                      <?php echo ($tool_stats == 1) ? "Approved" : 
                       (($tool_stats == 0)  ? "Pending" : "Cancelled");?>
                                                                            
                        </label>
                        </center>
                        </td>

                        <td class="hide_me">
                          <center>
                            <input name="chk_id[]" type="checkbox" 
                            class="subCheckbox" value="<?php echo 
                            $row['tools_req_id'];?>">
                          </center>
                        </td>

                        <?php
                                                                                
                           echo "</tr>";                                       
                                   }                                           
                                }
                             }
                          }
                        ?>
              </tbody>
          </table>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

PHP AJAX code

```
<?php

include('../include/connect.php');

$getChangeStatus = $_POST['status'];
$result = mysqli_query($con,"CALL GetGroupedToolsRequest('$getChangeStatus')");
$con->next_result();

if(mysqli_num_rows($result)>0)
{
while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) 
{ 
    $tool_stats = $row['tools_stats'];
    $row_stats = $row['req_stats'];
    // $tern = ($tool_stats == 1) ? "1" : (($tool_stats == 2)  ? "2" : "other"); <<< don't delete sample
    if($row['tools_stats'] == '0')
    {
        if($row_stats != '2')
        {
        echo "<tr>";
        echo "<td><a href='form_table_approval.php?ID=". $row['tr_sub'] . "&&" . $row['tools_stats'] ."' style='color:red;'>" . $row['tr_sub'] . "</a></td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['tools_request_department'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['tools_request_section'] . "</td>";
        echo "<td>" . $row['tools_request_leader'] . "</td>";
        if($tool_stats == '1')
        {
            echo "<td>" . $row['tools_request_reason_grp'] . "</td>";
        }
        elseif ($tool_stats == '0') 
        {
            echo "<td>" . $row['tools_request_reason_grp'] . "</td>";
        }
        else
        {
            echo "<td>" . $row['reason_cancel'] . "</td>";
        }       
?>
<td>
    <center>
        <label data-id="<?php echo $row['ID'];?>"
            class="statusButton <?php echo ($tool_stats == 1) ? 'label-success' : (($tool_stats == 2)  ? 'label-danger' : 'label-warning');?> ">
            <?php echo ($tool_stats == 1) ? "Approved" : (($tool_stats == 0)  ? "Pending" : "Cancelled");?>
        </label>
    </center>
</td>

<?php
    echo "</tr>";
        }
        }
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Hi, can you explain in short what exactly doesn't work ?

Comment: Hi @Swati I want to access a data from other status, example is if I cancel a bunch of data inside my CONTROL-1381 data it will display the remaining pending data and then the cancelled data will be inside my status cancelled and which is grouped also.

Comment: I hard coded my table inside ajax PHP file

Comment: problem is fronend or backend ? Sorry i still didn't got :P what you are trying to achieve here .

Comment: Problem is both haha backend and front end. Haha it is okay. Hmmm in my backend The value of status depends on what status by default. I set it in `0,1,2`, the data will always be updated when changing status. So when the status is updated partially, the data inside that default status I should separate it to other grouped status for example is I have a data that is pending and inside of that data I will cancel only partial data it will go to the cancel status.

Comment: so now when you update status of only few record all record are getting updated ? If yes there must be id which is unique to that row why not pass ids for checkboxes whose status you need to change at your backend ?

Comment: Sorry late reply, Hmm good idea I will try this now and see if it can work through my code. Will get back to asking you if will it did not work haha. Thanks :D

Comment: Hi @Swati still it did not work it returned null for me and can't get the values in the other status. Is it possible for this to be manipulated by `HTML DOM` ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/230308/discussion-between-swati-and-error-401).